# Unable to Use Pandas In IDLE

Tags: python, pandas

I installed *Python3.8* then installed pandas through miniconda.

However, when `import pandas as pd` in IDLE I get the following error

```
import pandas as pd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

Comment: It's seems like pandas wasn't installed as part of your installation, try to go back to minicoda and check it or just send the command 'python3.8 -m pip install pandas' in your terminal

Comment: Type `conda list pandas` and check if it has pandas installed or not in your venv.

Comment: This means you do not have pandas or the system can't find pandas in the list of  libraries. Python has internally a list directories which you can find by running ```import sys; sys.path```. You might also want to check if you have multiple versions of python installed.